# Button doesn't work on google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working to link an image in my Google Sheet document to a specific cell in another tab. I'm doing this by building a simple function that will do this. However, when I assign the function and then click on the image, I then get the error :

> Script function "test" could not be found

When I run the function in the script manager interface, it works fine. It's when I try to actually use it in the sheet with the image.

Function Script :

```js
function test() 
{ 
    Browser.msgBox("You clicked it!"); 
}
```

It turned out that the document owner had left their job and ownership rights had been moved to someone else. Can it matter ? 
The error is : [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ2v2.png)

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the assigned function name does not include the () brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Did a little snippet just to demonstrate on how you might approach this:

I used the sample from [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) on creating a button (in your case it's image) which responds to a click event. I'm using a bound script.

```
//in bounds script, this integral function triggers as soon as you open the spreadsheet
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .createMenu('Dialog')
      .addItem('Click Me', 'test')
      .addToUi();
}

//Then I attached your test function
function test() 
{ 
    Browser.msgBox("You clicked it!"); 
}
```

And sure enough upon clicking the button, the test function triggered:

[image]

Comment: the function OnOpen doesn't work too. I put a trigger : launch at oppening. But it work when i duplicate the spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm not sure the code is the problem. Cause if I duplicate the spreadsheet it work ...
I can't post the whole code, there is sensitive information ...